# Is the correct use of this sheet-metal part to separate SPD from sole?

Tags: shoes, cleat, spd

Since it was bent during clipping in/out, this tells me that this flimsy sheet metal part (the "spacer"?) should not be where I installed it.

[image: SPD cleat installation]

Should it be installed at all? Is the correct use of this (now bent) sheet-metal part to separate the SPD cleat (SM-SH51) from sole?

##### Related

- [Are cleat backing plates for protecting carbon sole?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/90018/48599)

Comment: Where did you get this piece from?

Comment: @MaplePanda It came with the shoes (and cleats). The included large-poster user manual was also unclear about where that part goes, despite (or perhaps due to) being in 32 languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sheet is in the correct place and installed where it should be. As far as I am aware, it is there to protect the shoe from damage, and is not really required. Without it the soles can get a bit chewed up.  Options you have are remove it completely (probably what I would do), or possibly straighten it and reinstall. Make sure it is not raised at the lip if you reuse it.

Comment: *...and is not really required*  That little metal plate can be **very** necessary if the soles of your shoes are soft enough that the cleat digs so far in that it becomes impossible to clip in.  I have an otherwise really nice pair of Lake MX332s that suffer from that annoying issue.